# Replace bold to italic in google docs using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

How to achieve a find and replace a bold font to italic using app script for Google docs. Note that it has to replace only the bold ones to italic and not all the text.

Say. A sample text

A quick brown fox **jumps over a lazy dog a quick brown fox** jumps over a lazy dog a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

This is slightly awkward because there is nothing like "text node in bold" in Google Documents; the [Text element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) does not have much internal structure. The solution seems to be to loop over its characters and test each on being bold. When the ranges of bold text are identified in the loop, they are set to italic with `setItalic` method. At the end, bold is removed from all text.

```
function bold2italic() {  
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var text = doc.getBody().editAsText();
  var startBold = 0;
  var bold = false; 
  for (var i = 0; i < text.getText().length; i++) {
    if (text.isBold(i) && !bold) {
      startBold = i;
      bold = true;
    }
    else if (!text.isBold(i) && bold) {
      bold = false;
      text.setItalic(startBold, i-1, true);
    }
  }
  if (bold) {
    text.setItalic(startBold, i-1, true);
  }  
  text.setBold(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [getTextAttributeIndices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getTextAttributeIndices()) of [Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) class.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
  var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs()
  for(p of paragraphs) {
    var text = p.editAsText();
    var idxs = text.getTextAttributeIndices();
    var offset = 0
    var endOffset = (i + 1 < idxs.length ? idxs[i + 1] : text.getText().length)
    if (endOffset == 0) {
      continue
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < idxs.length; i++) {
      offset = idxs[i]
      endOffset = (i + 1 < idxs.length ? idxs[i + 1] : text.getText().length)
      var str = text.getText().substring(offset, endOffset)
      var link = text.getLinkUrl(offset)
      var isBold = text.isBold(offset)
      var color = text.getForegroundColor(offset)
      if (isBold) {
        Logger.log("(" + offset + "," + endOffset + ") isBold:" + isBold + " color:" + color + " link:" + link + " text:" + str + "")
        var endOffsetInclusive = endOffset - 1
        text.setBold(offset, endOffsetInclusive, false)
        text.setItalic(offset, endOffsetInclusive, true)

      }
    }
  }
}
```